# The minimum spanning tree： prim and kruskal

Tags: algorithm, sorting, priority-queue

For the prim algorithm for STL priority queue optimization and the algorithm using c ++ sort kruskal, what types of graphs are suitable for these two algorithms?

Comment: what do you mean by types of graphs?

Comment: Dense and sparse graphs

Answer (score 1):

As you might already know,

Prim is good for dense graphs, and Kruskal is good for sparse ones.

With Kruskal, the algorithm complexity is dominated by sorting the edges.

So it's big O is `O(E log E)` in general cases with normal efficient sorts.

With Prim, the complexity is similar with Dijkstra's algorithm. (You can modify Dijkstra code into Prim with ease)

So it's like `O((V+E) log(V))` with priority queue(heap).

So when the Graph is sparse(`E < V`), Kruskal is `O(E log E)` and Prim is `O(V log V)`, so Kruslak wins.

And when the Graph is dense(`E is close to V^2-1`), Prim is `O(V^2 log V^2)` and Prim is `O(V^2 log V)`, so Prim wins.

But in most cases, you can use both algorithm without noticeable differences.